# Center animation in browser

Tags: jquery, animation, center

I am creating a portfolio section similar to TypeCode (http://typecode.com/work/). I have simple jQuery animations expanding and contracting divs on click. Is there a way to centralise the divs in the browser on each click as they do on TypeCode?

```
    // Select portfolio item
var active = false;
$('.portfolio-item').click(function(e) {

    // Check if alternative tab is open and then close it
     if ( $('#one').css("height") == "220px" ) {
        $('#one').animate({
            height: '110px',
        }, 1000, function() {
            // Animation complete    
        });
        active = false;
     }; // End if

    if ( $('#two').css("height") == "220px" ) {
        $('#two').animate({
            height: '110px',
        }, 1000, function() {
            // Animation complete    
        });
        active = false;
     }; // End if

    if (active == false) {
        $('.portfolio-item').css("height", "110px");

        $(this).animate({
            height: '220px',
        }, 1000, function() {
            // Animation complete    
        });

        active = true;
    }; // End if


}); // End click function


// Close portfolio item
$('.close').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(this).parents('.portfolio-item').animate({
        height: '110px',
    }, 1000, function() {

    });

    active = false;
});
```

Here is the  basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Avu9/1/

As you can see, if you click on an alternative tab (from the first 2 only) the current one is closed and the new one opened. This works well for a small amount of content but with bigger content this does not display very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beardyco/3GXXq/)

```
$('article').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('state-collapsed');
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

This should hopefully help

Comment: Thank you so much, this is most helpful!